# How can I count the students on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, nosql, count, mongodb-3.2

I would like to display the list of students who have passed at least 3 courses at ENSA with more than 60.

```
db.etudiants.insert({
    nom: 'emile',
    prenom: 'josé',
    cours_reussis: [{
        nom_cours: 'SO2',
        periodes: NumberInt(60),
        note: 70,
        date_reussite: NumberInt(2015),
        dispense: true,
        nom_ecole: 'ENSA'
    }, {
        nom_cours: 'IBD',
        periodes: NumberInt(60),
        note: 80,
        date_reussite: NumberInt(2015),
        dispense: true,
        nom_ecole: 'ENSA'
    }, {
        nom_cours: 'GEB',
        periodes: NumberInt(60),
        note: 65,
        date_reussite: NumberInt(2016),
        dispense: true,
        nom_ecole: 'ENSA'
    }]
})

db.etudiants.insert({
    nom: "larhemouchi",
    prenom: "zouhair",
    cours_reussis: [
      {
        nom_cours: "PAI",
        periodes: NumberInt(60),
        note: 68,
        date_reussite: NumberInt(2015),
        dispense: true,
        nom_ecole: "ENSA"
      }, 
      {
        nom_cours: "GEB",
        periodes: NumberInt(60),
        note: 78,
        date_reussite: NumberInt(2014),
        dispense: true,
        nom_ecole: "ENSA"
      }
    ]
})
```

In truth I tried and I am a bit ready to answer but I do not know how to have the students who have successfully 3 subjects.

here is my answer

```
  db.etudiants.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        'nom': 1,
        'prenom': 1,
        'cours_reussis': 1
    }
  }, 
  {
    $unwind: '$cours_reussis'
  }, 
  {
    $match: {
        'cours_reussis.note': {
            $gt: 60
        },
        'cours_reussis.nom_ecole': "ENSA"
    }
  }, 
  {
    $group: {
        '_id': {
            'nom': '$nom',
            'prenom': '$prenom',
            'cours_reussis.note': '$cours_reussis.note',
            'cours_reussis.nom_ecole': '$cours_reussis.nom_ecole'
        },
    }
  }
])
```

I would just like the students who have successfully taken 3 courses. In our database, the student who has successfully completed 3 courses is "emile josé".

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
db.etudiants.aggregate([
 {
   $unwind: '$cours_reussis'
 }, 
 {
   $match: {
       'cours_reussis.note': {
           $gt: 60
       },
       'cours_reussis.nom_ecole': "ENSA"
   }
 }, 
 {
   $group: {
       '_id': {
           'nom': '$nom',
           'prenom': '$prenom',
       }, 
       'num_courses' : { "$sum" : 1 }
   }
 }, 
 { $match : { 
      'num_courses' : { '$gte' : 3 }
  }
 }
])
```

Does this meet your criteria?

Note that the only changes I made to your aggregation were the following:

- I limited the '_id' to just the 'nom' and 'prenom' fields
- I used [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to count the number of completed courses
- The initial $projection stage was removed, as the aggregation can perform this optimization [automatically](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/).